# Add Java GUI to C client

Tags: java, c++, c, user-interface, java-native-interface

I have written a fully functional chat program in C. The server starts up and allows multiple clients to connect and talk to each other, all via command line. However I would like to try adding a GUI to this program, but all of the C/C++ GUI packages seem to have a steep learning curve just to get started. Is there any way to write a GUI using Swing and connect it to the C code underneath?

For example, I would like to type some text into a box, click "send" and have it call the C function which deals with sending text. Is this possible? And if so, is it very difficult?

I can provide code if needed. I am also open to suggestions on which C++ GUI package might be most appropriate for this kind of program.

Comment: There are many different ways this could be done. How easy it would be and what method was most appropriate would depend on the architecture of your current `C` code. I would be tempted to look into a native (portable) `C++` GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible. You would have to use `JNI`. You should really consider the learning curve of doing `JNI` vs learning whatever GUI framework you want to use you C/C++.

As someone who has done this on multiple professional projects though, I really would warn against it. It can produce very hard to find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

[Tcl/Tk](http://tcl.tk/) Used to be the scripting language of choice if you wanted  to provide a bunch of C/C++ methods with a (not too complicated) GUI. Python also provides GUI element via PyQT and PyKDE. I think it's much easier to use a scripting language like this to bind to C then trying to do Swing<=>C/C++ bridging.